# Difference between get and copy for Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I usually use the copy method for a selection of columns from my dataframe:

```
features_copy = df[['column1', 'column2']].copy()
```

I've noticed the get method also being used:

```
features_get = df.get(['column1', 'column2'])
```

What's the difference between the two? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analogous to the `dict.get` method, the `DataFrame.get` method has a `default` parameter whose value is returned if the specified key does not exist.

By default, the `default` parameter is set to `None`, so if the key does not exist, `df.get(['column1', 'column2'])` returns `None`.

In contrast, `df[['column1', 'column2']]` will raise a `KeyError` exception if the key does not exist.